# How to apply shadow at end corner of the circular path in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need to apply the shadow for the end of the circular path like the below image. I have used the canvas.drawPath to render the path. I have tried using canvas.drawShadow but using this, the shadow gets applied whole path instead of end corner of the path.

[image]

Comment: You can specify 2 points and add shadows to them. Possible to show code?

Answer (score -1):

**Apply shadow like that and addjust this from the offset i mention below example to do this**

```
boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.grey[200],
        blurRadius: 2.0, // has the effect of softening the shadow
        spreadRadius: 2.0, // has the effect of extending the shadow
        offset: Offset(
          5.0, // horizontal, move right 10
          5.0, // vertical, move down 10
        ),
      )
    ],
```

Comment: OP has used CustomPaint widget which do not have boxShadow parameter